# Return AJAX data before iterating parent loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry guys and gals, can't seem to wrap my head around this one, despite the various scenarios I've read online. So here is the situation:

I've got an array of strings called `recipientsList`

For each string in that array, I want to make an AJAX call that passes the string in as a parameter, then returns the data from the AJAX to my callback function.

My code is below. What is happening is that if I have three strings in the `recipientsList` array, then my `expandDistributionList` function gets called 3 times, but the code never hits the success portion of the AJAX call until after my .each finishes iterating. Thoughts?

```
function expandDistributionList(emailAddress, cb) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/expandDistributionList",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this,
        data: {
            distListName: emailAddress,
        },          
        success: function(data) {
            cb(data);
        },
        error: function() {                
            ace.search.mainframeErrorSignal = $.signal({
                'message': 'Unable to expand distribution list.',
                'addClass': 'error',
                'sticky': true
            });
        }
   });
}

recipientsList.each(function(item) {
    expandDistributionList(item, function(data){
        if(data...) {
             //do some code here
        }
        else {
             //do something else
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,
I am not sure, but this worked with my code

```
    function sendAsJSON(url, data, async, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (successCallback != null) {
                    successCallback(data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (errorData) {
                if (errorCallback != null) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

would you mind changing "GET" to "POST" and add contenttype.

Comment: hmm, not sure how your code above will fix the issue of the ajax calls completing after the .each finishes. Can you explain?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure, I tried looking putting some of my code in a loop which worked fine. would you mind giving this one a try?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7330771/1955342

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behaviour of JavaScript event model, your callbacks where queued in event queue and will be executed after the main code finished work;

And because my English is poor, I get some description from book *Async JavaScript* for this

> The ease of event scheduling in JavaScript is one of the language’s most
>   powerful features. Async functions like setTimeout make delayed execution
>   simple, without spawning threads. JavaScript code can never be interrupted,
>   report erratum because events can be queued only while code is running; they can’t fire until
>   it’s done.

You can chain Your async requests using promise, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612894/how-to-chain-ajax-calls-using-jquery) is great example

Comment: This makes sense, but it doesn't really shed light on how to code around the problem. Could you post a code solution that I could follow?

Comment: @Leann Why this behaviour is the problem for You? You can not stop you loop and wait for request to success unless You make your request synchronous

Comment: I thought that setting async: false was trouble because it could seriously freeze up the browser, thus I was looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes this could seriously freeze up the browser, and this is really bad. So am I correct that You want to execute your async requests one after another?