# jQuery continue with next loop (.each) on .ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I have a number of checkboxes and if a checkbox is checked I am sending its value with .ajax.
At the moment I am using `async : false` to make sure it loops from the next after the ajax success.
However, it kind of freezes the browser until it completes `.each` loop.

I saw something similar done here: [jQuery continue loop execution after ajax success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330728/jquery-continue-loop-execution-after-ajax-success) but can't figure out how to adapt it to my case where I am using `.each` instead of `for`

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {                      
    $.ajax({
        async : false,
        url:"import.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id, val:val},
        success:function(data) {
            //do some action
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same principle from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330753/378779:

```
var elements = $("input:checkbox:checked")

var i = 0;
doLoop();

function doLoop() {
    if ( i >= elements.length ) {
        return;
    }

    // To get the element we are up to: $(elements[i])

    $.ajax({
        async : false,
        url:"import.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id, val:val},
        success:function(data) {
            //do some action
            i++
            doLoop()
        }
    });
}
```

Presumably you'll want to change `data:{id:id, val:val}` to use the id and value from the individual checkbox, so before the `.ajax()` call you will probably want to:

```
let e = $(elements[i])
```

And to get the id and value:

```
data:{id:e.attr('id'), val:e.val()}
```

Comment: strangely I have `let e = $(elements[i]);
  var id = e.attr('name');
  var val = e.val();` but both id and val come empty

Comment: It works for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/kmoser/7q8fgovj/

Comment: Correct it does work. I was setting `let e = $(elements[i])` outside the `function doLoop() {`. Thanks a lot!